# Using Postman to access OAuth 2.0 Google APIs

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-api-client, postman, google-oauth

I am trying to access [Proximity Google API](https://developers.google.com/beacons/proximity/guides?hl=en) using [Postman chrome app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en). I have followed tutorials on postman and google dev website but I'm still getting 401 error message.

**What am I doing?**

- Step 1 - Enable Proximity API:

In order to use Proximity API, it has to be first enabled in Google Dev console. 
Using [this](https://developers.google.com/beacons/proximity/get-started) tutorial I have enabled support for Proximity API for my project

- Step 2 - Get the credentials:

According to [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) tutorial, I need to get client ID and secret. This is where I am confused. Credentials->Add credentials->OAuth2.0 client ID->select Chrome App radio button (since I am using Postman)->enter last part of Postman's Chrome Web store URL [which is [fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop]](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en)->hit create button These steps will only generate a client ID, not a secret..am I doing something wrong?

From the Google Dev console, one can download an JSON file which has client id, auth URI and Token URI
[image]

I downloaded this but this is of little help if I am using Postman. I am guessing this JSON file is something that can be included in a JS application.

- Step 3 - Use Postman to test the API

[image]

**What am I getting?**
[image]

And, once I click on the debug URL, I see the following screen

[image]

Answer (score 217):

Postman will query Google API impersonating a Web Application

Generate an OAuth 2.0 token:

1. Ensure that the Google APIs are enabled
2. Create an OAuth 2.0 client ID

   - Go to Google Console -> API -> OAuth consent screen

     - Add `getpostman.com` to the Authorized domains. Click Save.
   - Go to Google Console -> API -> Credentials

     - Click 'Create credentials' -> OAuth client ID -> Web application

       - Name: 'getpostman'
       - Authorized redirect URIs: `https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback`
   - Copy the generated `Client ID` and `Client secret` fields for later use
3. In Postman select Authorization tab and select "OAuth 2.0" type. Click 'Get New Access Token'

   - Fill the GET NEW ACCESS TOKEN form as following

     - Token Name: 'Google OAuth getpostman'
     - Grant Type: 'Authorization Code'
     - Callback URL: `https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback`
     - Auth URL: `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth`
     - Access Token URL: `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token`
     - Client ID: `Client ID` generated in the step 2 (e.g., '123456789012-abracadabra1234546789blablabla12.apps.googleusercontent.com')
     - Client Secret: `Client secret` generated in the step 2 (e.g., 'ABRACADABRAus1ZMGHvq9R-L')
     - Scope: see the Google docs for the required OAuth scope (e.g., https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform)
     - State: Empty
     - Client Authentication: "Send as Basic Auth header"
   - Click 'Request Token' and 'Use Token'
4. Set the method, parameters, and body of your request according to the Google docs

Comment: If using the Insomnia client, then both the Authorized Domain and Redirect URI are `https://insomnia.rest` Ref: https://support.insomnia.rest/article/38-authentication

Comment: This seemed to work until I get to the next issue which *seems* to be related to postman not supporting google 2FA authentication. Here is the message: "An application is requesting permission to access your Google Account." Any idea?

Comment: I get “This browser or app may not be secure” result

Comment: This flow does not work anymore: Google forbids authentication outside of main browsers. Postman team says they're working on "Authorize using browser" feature - https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/7700

Comment: Can absolutely verify this works with a g suite tenant.  Only thing that could be better is how to automatically refresh the token ... my google api scrapes take well over an hour (the token lifetime)

Comment: I was able to get a token and use it, however when sending a request it returns with a response from google asking me to select which account to proceed with? The preview mode is not responding to any input. I have only one account... (using PostmanRuntime/7.24.1)

Comment: Please marked this as correct answer <3 Thx alot brother....very well explained

Comment: Found similar guide with snapshot [here](https://medium.com/@pnatraj/google-cloud-api-with-postman-f4cf070e665f)

Comment: If you get an error for Scope, you can find a list of all the values [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes).

Comment: Also note that scopes are separated by a regular whitespace in case you need to require multiple scopes. Like `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.userschema`

Comment: If you get the  “This browser or app may not be secure” result, then please checkmark the "authorize using browser" tickbox, as explained by team postman themselves in github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/7700

Comment: Login good, request https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels, fails with:

{
    "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "The caller does not have permission",
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "youtube.api.CommonRequestError",
                "reason": "ERROR_MISSING_SCOPE"
            }
        ],
        "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
    }
}

Answer (score 72):

The best way I found so far is to go to the Oauth playground here: https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

1. Select the relevant google api category, and then select the scope inside that category in the UI.
2. Get the authorization code by clicking "authorize API" blue button.
   Exchange authorization code for token by clicking the blue button.
3. Store the OAuth2 token and use it as shown below.

In the HTTP header for the REST API request, add: "Authorization: Bearer ". Here, Authorization is the key, and "Bearer ". For example: "Authorization: Bearer za29.KluqA3vRtZChWfJDabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz6nAZ0y6ElzDT3yH3MT5"

Comment: This workflow resolved my problem!
Just to complement the explanation, after "Exchange authorization code for token" I copied the value at "Access token" field and used it as Authorization Bearer on Postman

Answer (score 62):

The current answer is outdated. Here's the up-to-date flow:

> The approach outlined here still works (28th of july 2022, confirmed by Jordy)

We will use the *YouTube Data API* for our example. Make changes accordingly.

> Make sure you have [enabled your desired API](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library) for your project.

### Create the OAuth 2.0 Client

1. Visit [`https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials`](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials)
2. Click on **CREATE CREDENTIALS**
3. Select **OAuth client ID**
4. For **Application Type** choose **Web Application**
5. Add a **name**
6. Add following URI for **Authorized redirect URIs**

```
https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback
```

7. Click **Save**
8. Click on the OAuth client you just generated
9. In the **Topbar** click on **DOWNLOAD JSON** and save the file somewhere on your machine.

> We will use the file later to authenticate Postman.

### Authorize Postman via OAuth 2.0 Client

1. In the **Auth** tab under **TYPE** choose **OAuth 2.0**
2. For values under **Configuration Options** enter the values found inside the **client_secret_[YourClientID].json** file we **downloaded** in **step 9**
3. Click on **Get New Access Token**
4. Make sure your settings are as follows:

[Click here to see the settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TC87e.jpg)

(In addition, multiple scope can be as follows, space-delimited: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email [https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"](https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile%22))

5. Click on **Request Token**
6. A new browser tab/window will open
7. Once the browser tab opens, login via the appropriate Google account
8. Accept the consent screen
9. Done

> Ignore the browser message "Not safe" etc. This will be shown until your app has been screened by Google officials. In this case it will always be shown since Postman is the app.

Comment: How does this have no votes two years later. It is the only solution that still works

Comment: Updated the post to reflect your confirmation that it still works.

Comment: I confirmed that it works now too.

Comment: March 5, 2022 works perfectly!
EDIT I would only add that for adding comments and other higher-permissions tasks, youtube.force-ssl is an appropriate scope.

Comment: The callback URL you add to google console should be https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/browser-callback

Comment: Confirming @user3447228 that callback URL https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/browser-callback works.

Comment: Still works on 28th of july 2022

Answer (score 14):

1. go to https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials
2. create web application credentials.

[Postman API Access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eapqh.png)

3. use these settings with oauth2 in Postman:

   - Auth URL = https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
   - Access Token URL = https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token

     4. Choose Scope for the HTTP API
     5. Generate Token
     6. to add Schema use:

SCOPE = https: //www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.userschema

### post https: //www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/customer/customer-id/schemas

```
{
  "fields": [
    {
      "fieldName": "role",
      "fieldType": "STRING",
      "multiValued": true,
      "readAccessType": "ADMINS_AND_SELF"
    }
  ],
  "schemaName": "SAML"
}
```

7. to patch user use:

SCOPE = https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user

PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/admin@email.com

```
 {
  "customSchemas": {
     "SAML": {
       "role": [
         {
          "value": "arn:aws:iam::123456789123:role/Admin,arn:aws:iam::123456789123:saml-provider/GoogleApps",
          "customType": "Admin"
         }
       ]
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I figured out that I was not generating Credentials for the right app type.
If you're using Postman to test Google oAuth 2 APIs, select 
 
**Credentials -> Add credentials -> OAuth2.0 client ID -> Web Application**.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This is an old question, but it has no chosen answer, and I just solved this problem myself. Here's my solution:

1. Make sure you are set up to work with your Google API in the first place. See Google's [list of prerequisites](https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/prereqs). I was working with Google My Business, so I also went through it's [Get Started](https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/get-started) process.
2. In the [OAuth 2.0 playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground), Step 1 requires you to select which API you want to authenticate. Select or input as applicable for your case (in my case for Google My Business, I had to input https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.business.manage into the "Input your own scopes" input field). *Note: this is the same as what's described in step 6 of the "Make a simple HTTP request" section of the [Get Started](https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/get-started) guide*.
3. Assuming successful authentication, you should get an "Access token" returned in the "Step 1's result" step in the OAuth playground. Copy this token to your clipboard.
4. Open Postman and open whichever collection you want as necessary.
5. In Postman, make sure "GET" is selected as the request type, and click on the "Authorization" tab below the request type drop-down.
6. In the Authorization "TYPE" dropdown menu, select "Bearer Token"
7. Paste your previously copied "Access Token" which you copied from the OAuth playground into the "Token" field which displays in Postman.
8. Almost there! To test if things work, put https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/ into the main URL input bar in Postman and click the send button. You should get a JSON list of accounts back in the response that looks something like the following:

   ```
   {
       "accounts": [
           {
               "name": "accounts/REDACTED",
               "accountName": "REDACTED",
               "type": "PERSONAL",
               "state": {
                   "status": "UNVERIFIED"
               }
           },
           {
               "name": "accounts/REDACTED",
               "accountName": "REDACTED",
               "type": "LOCATION_GROUP",
               "role": "OWNER",
               "state": {
                   "status": "UNVERIFIED"
               },
               "permissionLevel": "OWNER_LEVEL"
           }
       ]
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Google has changed the Access Token URL: `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token`.
It now needs to be: `https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token`

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to the top answer by @DimaTx, don't forget to put checkmark on the "authorize using browser" tickbox, as explained by team postman themselves in github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/7700

This will prevent/solve the “This browser or app may not be secure” result.

[image]