# Trying to connect Google Oath2 in Postman

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-workspace

We have a G Suite for Education. I want to create a new gmail user for each of our students.

I [enabled Gmail as told in this documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python) and downloaded the credentials.json file.

I than opened POSTMAN and created a post request for this URL:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth
```

I used the parameters from credentials.json:

```
client_id: (as in json file)
response_type: code 
scope: openid%20email
redirect_api: http://localhost
```

The response is html of the login page. 
I tried **token**, **id_token** instead of code but response says unsupported_response_type.

What I try to do is to use the following request to create user, which says login required.

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users
```

Am I on the wrong way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Postman to access OAuth 2.0 Google APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32076503/using-postman-to-access-oauth-2-0-google-apis)

Comment: Read this article: https://www.jhanley.com/google-oauth-2-0-testing-with-curl/