# Download a tab of a google sheet as a CSV file

Tags: curl, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

This used to work:

curl 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xaGu5Cd0kRPKy0v-EaVxgfnUxaxWlgDhfhfgRQy6hrc/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&sheet=Inv_Summary&range=A:G'

The segment tqx=out:csv specified the format, sheet specfied the tab name, and range the columns to bring out.

Now if I do this, I get:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Moved Temporarily</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Moved Temporarily</H1>
The document has moved <A HREF="https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin? service=wise&amp;passive=1209600&amp;continue=https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_fZoLgNGB3fXZqgzCr1gtDnJ2Gowi4dFgovmjsSPHy8/gviz/tq?tqx%3Dout:csv%26sheet%3DInv_Summary%26range%3DA:G&amp;followup=https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_fZoLgNGB3fXZqgzCr1gtDnJ2Gowi4dFgovmjsSPHy8/gviz/tq?tqx%3Dout:csv%26sheet%3DInv_Summary%26range%3DA:G&amp;ltmpl=sheets">here</A>.
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

That long response, broken to make it more easily parsible by people

```
<A HREF="https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin? 
service=wise&amp;passive=1209600&amp;

continue= 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_fZoLgNGB3fXZqgzCr1gtDnJ2Gowi4dFgovmjsSPHy8/
gviz/tqtqx%3Dout:csv%26sheet%3DInv_Summary%26range%3DA:G&amp;

followup=
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_fZoLgNGB3fXZqgzCr1gtDnJ2Gowi4dFgovmjsSPHy8/
gviz/tq?tqx%3Dout:csv%26sheet%3DInv_Summary%26range%3DA:G&amp;
ltmpl=sheets">here</A>
```

You'll note that the followup URL is identical to the temp moved URL.

Now if I paste the original link after the curl statement into the address line in chrome, I get an immediate open a file to download, and it does the right thing.

Why isn't curl working to do this?

How do I get the old behaviour back?

Background:  I keep a google sheet that tracks my tree farm inventory.  The inventory is summarized on a pivot table.  A script scrapes the pivot table data, and uses it to generate HTML pages for my website.

Answer (score 2):

Gotta love informative messages.

- The spreadsheet in question was not publically readable.
- When google checked the file, curl did not pass an OAuth token.  Instead of saying something clever like, "This app did not present a valid token" it instead refers me to the web page version.
- Since I was already authorized in the browser, the *here* link worked.

to solve this problem you can do one of two things:

A:  Make the file publically readable -- anyone with the link can read it.  Since this is basically just book keeping stuff in inventory control, I don't care who reads it.

B:  Jump through the hoops to get OAuth working with Curl.  A good starting point for that is here:

https://www.daimto.com/how-to-get-a-google-access-token-with-curl/

It's been answered before on SO

[get google Oauth2 access token using ONLY curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66940072/get-google-oauth2-access-token-using-only-curl)

Comment: More proper thing to do compared to using wget. +1

Comment: At the risk of starting a conversation in comments, why would curl be "more proper" than wget?

Comment: more proper for your case as you would still have to retain and modify just a little on your existing code. That's what I believe thus I called it more proper than using wget that basically changes what you have. It's a personal thing. :D

Answer (score 1):

I remember an issue pertaining to output csv having a redirect for `curl` commands, can you try a `wget` with the same url? The issue comes and goes so I'll recommend a `wget` if it's acceptable.

#### Sample:

```
wget -O test.csv --no-check-certificate "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xaGu5Cd0kRPKy0v-EaVxgfnUxaxWlgDhfhfgRQy6hrc/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&sheet=Inv_Summary&range=A:G"
```

#### Output:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Didn't make a difference.  Are you doing this on the command line with curl?

Comment: @SherwoodBotsford, im trying it on an online curl emulator as im on the phone right now and asking a friend to provide a screenshot difference. If it doesn't work, I recall output csv is having a redirect issue in curl in the past and the way to overcome the issue is to use `wget` instead. Can you try `wget`?

Comment: Included actual command and output for `wget` command @SherwoodBotsford

Comment: Problem turned out to be permissions.  See my answer below.  Giving "anyone with link can view" permission returned the previous behaviour.

Comment: Hmm. Haven't encountered this one but it seems the proper approach to do.. Glad you were able to find it @SherwoodBotsford