# Using postman to get OAuth2 token using Google API

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, postman, google-oauth

I have an application and I want to send post requests to it using the Postman desktop app. The application uses OAuth2 with google as a provider.

I followed the instructions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53529534/2599537) answer here on stackoverflow, but there is a problem. Once I fill in the information in the form, and I click Request Token, a postman browser window opens asking me to login to google. I write my credentials and try to login but I get a message saying "This browser or app may not be secure":

[image]

What can I do? I tried creating an app password for postman specifically, but even when I use that, I get the same message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently an open issue.
As mentioned in this link.
It's WIP
[Link](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/7700)