# Google api credentials screen stuck spinning after adding a postman redirect URI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, oauth, postman, google-oauth

I have created a new project in Google cloud [console](https://console.cloud.google.com/) to experiment with Google OAuth flows. I have therefore set up *OAuth web app client credentials* using

`APIs & Services -> Credentials -> Create Credentials -> OAuth Client ID -> Web Application`

I want to be able to experiment with [postman](https://www.postman.com/) to request authorisation codes, access/refresh tokens etc. Once in the *Create OAuth client ID* I therefore add a postman callback URI (`https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback`) to the credentials' *Authorised Redirect URIs* as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61955225/1920203). However when I click *CREATE* at the bottom of the *Create OAuth client ID* screen, the screen does not update and just keeps spinning. I have waited for over 20 mins but to no avail. Is this a callback URI validation problem such that Google won't allow me to add this redirect URI to the credentials? I have tried to add the domain `oauth.pstmn.io` to the authorised domains in the project settings but to no avail. **When I don't include the redirect URI, the credentials are created with no problem** and I am returned to the main `APIs & Services -> Credentials` screen.

The user that I am using to make these changes owns the project and therefore I do not suspect it is a Google user permissions issue. I have also added the minimum number of fields (project name and support email) to the *OAuth consent screen* settings. I have also tried this whole process logged in on a different machine.

Comment: This might help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jjCauMywU2Q  if it doesnt let me know and i will check it in the morning

Comment: @DaImTo - your video did help as it lead me to this video instead: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pBVAyU4pZOU. I realised that you need to add at least one api scopes to the setup before specifying a callback uri.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that at least one api scope needs to be added to `OAuth consent screen->Scopes` before you set a redirect URI. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pBVAyU4pZOU) video explains the entire setup.

Answer (score 0):

https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/8296678/TzXtGzS2

you can use this public collection to learn more about how to set up auth token for google APIs